# Dans le but de / Avec le but de

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

I don't really understand why is *dans* used in this expression instead of *avec*, specially when I look up the word *dans* in the [dictionary](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/dans) and only when it is used in informal context, it means **with**.

However, according to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avec%20le%20but%20de%2Cdans%20le%20but%20de&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=2&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavec%20le%20but%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20le%20but%20de%3B%2Cc0), the sentence with **dans** seems to be the one by default.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word-by-word translation does not always work, especially when faced with idioms. Usage indeed favours "*dans le but de*" over "*avec le but de*".

Why is it constructed this way? I have no idea and cannot find the origin.

Something about [your Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avec%20le%20but%20de%2Cdans%20le%20but%20de&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=2&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavec%20le%20but%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20le%20but%20de%3B%2Cc0) is interesting though: the expression began to really be used in the XIX<sup>th</sup> Century. We may relate this to sports.

The « *but* » is the goal in sports too. The first example to come to mind is soccer, where it is the cage you have to put your ball *into*. Reading the [history of soccer on Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football), it seems to have known a great development in England around 1820-1830. France is not so far and may have taken example. Maybe there is connection, but **this is speculation**.

Sometimes, you just need to admit cultural differences change the way idioms are constructed and not overthink it.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I'm always looking for a *why*, instead of settling for just *because*.

Answer (score 2):

One meaning (7th) of *[dans](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/dans)* in your dictionary explains it well :

> **dans** *prép* (indique le but de l'action)        (purpose)  **in** *prep*
>
> > *Les hommes politiques devraient agir **dans** l'intérêt général.*
> >     *Politicians are supposed to act **in** the public interest.*

---

So I would translate *"Dans le but de"* by *"In the aim of"*

And *"Avec le but de"* by *"With the aim of"*.